# how to change back button title of navigation in iphone

Tags: iphone

How to not show Back Bar Button of navigation controller. When I am trying to write my title with " " then this is showing default title name (Root).

How to change it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if you don't want to see the back button, use below

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = nil ;
```

if you want to see your `text` instead of "Back" button. you could also define your `action:`.

```
 self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem =
      [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"MyOwnBackTitle"
               style: UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
               target:self
               action:@selector(backClicked:] autorelease];
```

Use below code to change the bar text,

```
UINavigationBar *bar = self.navigationController.navigationBar ;
bar.topItem.title = @"MY Title";
```

Comment: self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = nil ; is not working it is showing default title name instead. I am writing it in ViewLoad function.

Comment: @Jhaliya.. this is working great. But when i am trying to give @"" for BLANK value, button title is not appearing any screen. And When I am trying to give one space @" ", I am seeing one blank title button is apearing. I don't want to show button title on this screen and else screen i want to show  button .

Comment: @Ajay_Kumar  :means:your issue is sorted out ... Right ?

Comment: My issues is not sorted but your reply is right as par he question. I have 3 screen my first screen is splash screen this is coming for 1-2 sec only. After splash screen my 2nd screen is loading which has books list. I don't want to show BACK BUTTON in this screen. But whenever you will select any book pdf will be open there must be BACK BUTTON. I want to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Use this in the viewDidLoad method

```
[self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES animated:YES];
```

Comment: This is hiding backbutton from all screens. I have to hide OR don't show BACK button only from a specific screen. and also I m writing code for BACK Bar Button in ViewLoad function.

Comment: Go the the .m file of the view you would like to hide, and use the code to Hide that one ;)

Answer (score 0):

self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.title=@"Your Title";